# How does Tomcat work in AWS EC2

Tags: java, unix, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Could anyone educate me a big piture of the Amazon EC2 Unix instance? I would like to know how Tomcat works in an EC2 instance so that in the future I know how to reconfigure/customize it.

After I create/launch a new EC2 instance running with Tomcat server, everything seems to be well set up. It does not require additional configuration to have the Tomcat running and to deploy.

When I connect to my instance and walk through this UNIX server, I have no idea how the structure is designed. For example, where is Tomcat located and what is linking to the Tomcat so that from AWS managment console UI I can just start/stop the server with a few mouse clicks.

-
Please have me clarify if you found my statement unclear.

Comment: unix instance? did you mean Amazon Linux? there is no unix AMI available on AWs.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on linux version and in it you can find tomcat home directory(if prior included)
at /usr/share/tomcat .User can use putty to log in to that.
You might want to have a look [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-basic.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to install Tomcat yourself, from the packages you can find at [tomcat.apache.org](http://tomcat.apache.org/). You can install it on any OS you want, on any flavor of machine you can launch within EC2. You'll also get patches more quickly than the distro maintainers can, the file layouts will make sense, and you can get all the help you need from the Tomcat community via their users' mailing list without having to first explain that you have no idea where Tomcat is installed, where the configuration files are, etc.

Do you really need point-and-click starting and stopping of Tomcat?

If you just want to deploy a web application into the AWS Magic, consider using [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). I haven't used it, but it if actually does what they claim it does, it's pretty magical.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how the structure is designed. For example, where is Tomcat located and what is linking to the Tomcat

Assuming you're referring to Linux instance (again which Linux instance is another question)

but to answer what you want, run below commands on your instance:

```
# updatedb
# locate tomcat
```

The output of 2nd command will list you all the files/directories which has `tomcat` in their name. This way you will  be able to figure out the location where Tomcat resides.

Comment: To run the 2nd path, do I need to be in a particular path? Command "# locate tomcat" does not give me anything

Comment: No, you can run that command from wherever you are. do you have tomcat installed/running on this instance? In other words, What makes you believe that tomcat is installed on this instance?

Comment: Well, I have been able to deploy a demo web app via AWS Eclipse plugin and it is up and running. When I launched that instance, I chose Tomcat as the server. So I guess that should be enough for me to believe?

Comment: I ma not a java java guy. But you should se tomcat runniong in port 8080 by running `netstat -anp | grep 808` and also you should see a tomcat process by running `ps -eaf | grep tomcat`. Provide the output of both these commands.